# Cannot install JDK on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, jdk

I am struggling to install Oracle's JDK7 on my Windows 8.1.
I got the `jdk-7u51-windows-x64.exe` file from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html as I should, but when trying to launch it, I get this: [image: error] ; which in english means *This application cannot run on your PC - to find a version for your PC, please contact the software editor.* However, there is no W8 dedicated version of JDK as far as I can tell.

I get the same with the 32-bits version (`jdk-7u51-windows-i586.exe`).
I deactivated Windows SmartScreen and Windows Defender, no changes.
JDK6 works fine.

Comment: Why don't you try JDK8?

Comment: Because it is not a stable release ?

Comment: Do you happen to use the RT-Version of Windows 8.1?
Did you also try to install it with different compatibility-settings?

Comment: Are you running Windows RT?

Comment: No, I am running a simple W8.1 professional. I tried with W7 compatibility, same behaviour.

Comment: I use 'JDK_7U45_WINDOWS_I586' in my Windows 64 bit OS. There is no problem between 32 bit JDK and my 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the reason your install is failing is that you have a 32-bit edition of Windows 8.1 installed. That is why the jdk-7u51-windows-i586.exe works as it is built to target 32-bit editions of Windows. The x64 version of the JDK requires a 64-bit edition of Windows.

You can verify if your Windows installation is 64- or 32-bit from the System Control panel.